# Fatal Error when trying to save/load data from SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an application that currently works with no saving or loading of any kind. I need it to be able to save up to 20 different variables (string/long/integer).

Below is my .java - when you see the

```
debtAmount2 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
```

It has the (long) because it's being "put" as an double, but I can't do a sharedpref with double and had to make it a long.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.debtlist);

    //Name Displays
    TextView debtName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispName1);
    TextView debtName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispName2);
    TextView debtName3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispName3);
    TextView debtName4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispName4);
    TextView debtName5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispName5);

    //Amount Displays
    TextView debtAmt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispBal1);
    TextView debtAmt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispBal2);
    TextView debtAmt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispBal3);
    TextView debtAmt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispBal4);
    TextView debtAmt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispBal5);

    //Order Displays
    TextView dispDebtOrder1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispPayOrder1);
    TextView dispDebtOrder2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispPayOrder2);
    TextView dispDebtOrder3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispPayOrder3);
    TextView dispDebtOrder4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispPayOrder4);
    TextView dispDebtOrder5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispPayOrder5);

    TextView terminate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminate);

    Integer trigger = 0;
    Integer stopper = 1;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (debtNames1 == null && extras != null && trigger == 0) {
        debtNames1 = extras.getString("nickname");
        debtName1.setText("" + debtNames1);
        debtAmount1 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount1);
        debtAmt1.setText("" + amount);
        trigger++;
    }
    else if (debtNames1 != null) {
        debtName1.setText("" + debtNames1);
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount1);
        debtAmt1.setText("" + amount);  
        stopper++;
    }

    if (debtNames2 == null && extras != null && trigger == 0) {
        debtNames2 = extras.getString("nickname");
        debtName2.setText(debtNames2);
        debtAmount2 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount2);
        debtAmt2.setText("" + amount);
        trigger++;
    }
    else if (debtNames2 != null) {
        debtName2.setText("" + debtNames2);
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount2);
        debtAmt2.setText("" + amount);          
        stopper++;
    }

    if (debtNames3 == null && extras != null && trigger == 0) {
        debtNames3 = extras.getString("nickname");
        debtName3.setText(debtNames3);
        debtAmount3 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount3);
        debtAmt3.setText("" + amount);
        trigger++;
    }
    else if (debtNames3 != null) {
        debtName3.setText("" + debtNames3);
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount3);
        debtAmt3.setText("" + amount);  
        stopper++;
    }

    if (debtNames4 == null && extras != null && trigger == 0) {
        debtNames4 = extras.getString("nickname");
        debtName4.setText(debtNames4);
        debtAmount4 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount4);
        debtAmt4.setText("" + amount);
        trigger++;
    }
    else if (debtNames4 != null) {
        debtName4.setText("" + debtNames4);
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount4);
        debtAmt4.setText("" + amount);  
        stopper++;
    }

    if (debtNames5 == null && extras != null && trigger == 0) {
        debtNames5 = extras.getString("nickname");
        debtName5.setText(debtNames5);
        debtAmount5 = (long) extras.getDouble("outstandingBalance");
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount5);
        debtAmt5.setText("" + amount);
        trigger++;
    }
    else if (debtNames5 != null) {
        debtName5.setText("" + debtNames5);
        String amount = String.valueOf(debtAmount5);
        debtAmt5.setText("" + amount);          
        stopper++;
    }

    if (stopper == 6) {
        terminate.setText("You have too many debts - get a job!");
        }
    else {
        terminate.setText("");
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("savedata", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putString("debtNames1", debtNames1);
    editor.putLong("debtAmount1", debtAmount1);
    editor.putLong("debtRate1", debtRate1);
    editor.putInt("debtOrder1", debtOrder1);
    editor.putInt("debtTerm1", debtTerm1);

    editor.putString("debtNames2", debtNames2);
    editor.putLong("debtAmount2", debtAmount2);
    editor.putLong("debtRate2", debtRate2);
    editor.putInt("debtOrder2", debtOrder2);
    editor.putInt("debtTerm2", debtTerm2);

    editor.putString("debtNames3", debtNames3);
    editor.putLong("debtAmount3", debtAmount3);
    editor.putLong("debtRate3", debtRate3);
    editor.putInt("debtOrder3", debtOrder3);
    editor.putInt("debtTerm3", debtTerm3);

    editor.putString("debtNames4", debtNames4);
    editor.putLong("debtAmount4", debtAmount4);
    editor.putLong("debtRate4", debtRate4);
    editor.putInt("debtOrder4", debtOrder4);
    editor.putInt("debtTerm4", debtTerm4);

    editor.putString("debtNames5", debtNames5);
    editor.putLong("debtAmount5", debtAmount5);
    editor.putLong("debtRate5", debtRate5);
    editor.putInt("debtOrder5", debtOrder5);
    editor.putInt("debtTerm5", debtTerm5);

    editor.commit();
}
```

The fatal error I received has been solved; however, the app is not retaining data when moving from this activity to the one that I am "get"ing my extras from and back. It's replacing debtName1 each time. I'm not using a menu link, but the <-- instead.

Comment: How did you declare the variable `debtAmount1`? Is it a `long` or a `Long`? (Note the difference between lowercase and uppercase "L")

Comment: Please check again, in which line exactly the NPE happens. The only possible reason for an NPE in the line you showed is that editor is null. But then the NPE would have also appeared in the previous line. So I think something is wrong in your error description.

Comment: and that's what I get for declaring those wrong - thank you. Now it's just not displaying the loaded data - but I'm sure that's an issue in my if/statements. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATED ABOVE -- it's still not retaining data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putString("debtNames1", debtNames1);
        editor.putFloat("debtAmount1", amount1);
        editor.putLong("debtRate1", debtRate1);
        editor.putInt("debtTerm1", debtTerm1);

        editor.putString("debtNames2", debtNames2);
        editor.putFloat("debtAmount2", amount2);
        editor.putLong("debtRate2", debtRate2);
        editor.putInt("debtTerm2", debtTerm2);

        editor.putString("debtNames3", debtNames3);
        editor.putFloat("debtAmount3", amount3);
        editor.putLong("debtRate3", debtRate3);
        editor.putInt("debtTerm3", debtTerm3);

        editor.putString("debtNames4", debtNames4);
        editor.putFloat("debtAmount4", amount4);
        editor.putLong("debtRate4", debtRate4);
        editor.putInt("debtTerm4", debtTerm4);

        editor.putString("debtNames5", debtNames5);
        editor.putFloat("debtAmount5", amount5);
        editor.putLong("debtRate5", debtRate5);
        editor.putInt("debtTerm5", debtTerm5);

        editor.putFloat("timeSaved1", timeSaved1);
        editor.putFloat("timeSaved2", timeSaved2);
        editor.putFloat("timeSaved3", timeSaved3);
        editor.putFloat("timeSaved4", timeSaved4);
        editor.putFloat("timeSaved5", timeSaved5);

        editor.putFloat("totalDebt", totalDebt);
        editor.commit();
```